# How to return a Maybe or result from Maybe

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I'm on an Usecase and I have a repository, where I have all of the methods that I have to do, for instance :

```
class MyUseCase(
    private val myRepository: MyRepository
) {

    fun execute(example: String) { //First I don't know what to return here
    //Here I have to check if theres anything on the room db, for this I have this method
    myRepository.findLocally(example) // it returns a Maybe<MyObject>
    //Then if it returns an object I have to do another call that is 
    myRepository.findObject(example) //it will return a Maybe<List<OtherObject>>
    //So if we arrive to this, the usecase is done and I should return the last result.
    //if user doesn't search it before then I have to do an api call using
    myRepository.getFromApi(example) //it will return Single<List<OtherObject>>
    //When I get the result then I have to do two inserts using 
    myRepository.insertWord(example) : Completable
    //And then I want to add all the result from the api call it can be a List<MyObject> or a []
    myRepository.insertList(resultFromApi) : Completable

    }

}
```

My problem is that I do now know how to execute all of this or if I should split it or something, this is called from my presenter, so I want to return to my presenter the data to call the view.showData() for instance.

The idea, should execute it like this :

```
if(myRepository.findLocally(example)) {
  return myRepository.findObject(example)
}
else{
  myRepository.getFromApi(example)
  myRepository.insertWord(example)
  myRepository.insertList(resultFromApi)
}
```

### Edit

I'm looking the way to do it using RxJava.

This is how I'm trying to do it :

```
return myRepository.findLocally(example).flatMap {
            myRepository.findObject(example)
        }.switchIfEmpty {
            myRepository.getFromApi(example).flatMap { example ->
                example.flatMap {
                    myRepository.insertList(
                        MyExample(
                            it.id,
                            it.name,
                            it.description
                        )
                    )
                }
                myRepository.insertWord(example)

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :**
You can return `Any?` object

```
private val myRepository() : Any? {
    // Your stuff here
}
```

`Any` object basically means you can return anything you want, but be careful to check the return in your parent method.
The `?` means you can also return a `null` object. Check that too in your parent method.

**Method 2 :**
Or make all these calls from your method that calls this one, with `if` and `else`s

**Method 3 :**
Another way to do this is to return both with kind of "pointers" :

```
private val myRepository(resul1 : Object1, result2 : Object2, ...) {
    if (function_to_get_result1_fails)
        result1 = Object1() // You set result1 as a basic empty object of type Object1
    else if (function_to_get_result2_fails)
        result2 = Object2()
    // etc.
}
```

Then, in your parent method, make a check like this :

```
myRepository(object1, object2, ...)
if (object1.someDataInObject1 != -1) // Set an un-instancied variable as -1 to know if the object is empty or not
    doSomething()
else if (object2.someDataInObject2 != -1)
    doSomethingElse()
// etc.
```

However, prefer method 1, or maybe method 2, but method 3 is kinda "dirty" and consumes a lot of resources for nothing.

Comment: But I need to use rxjava right? if I call these calls I have to run them on a different thread...

Comment: As you wish, I guess the 2 first of your calls are dependant, so to make call 2, you need to wait for call 1 to finish. Try to read about synchronous / asynchronous tasks in android

Comment: You have any clue to how to do it using RxJava? And wait for every call?

Comment: This link provide informations about "blocking" calls, that means a call will block another one until it is not finished. I think this is what you need for your 2 first calls. Then you would combine this with asynchronous calls to make your other calls.
https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/rxjava-synchronous-blocking-call/